# Print 4-page form where the page breaks are set

Tags: cognito-forms

Can Cognito Forms print out as it is set up in the form, specifically, I have it set up to be a 4 page form, but it is not printing the form at where the page breaks are set?

Also, can it be printed without the status info regarding form name, receipt date, status since that takes up a whole page in of itself.

Answer (score 1):

When printing entries in Cognito Forms, the form appears as laid out, but is read-only and makes sure all information will appear, regardless of how much information is entered.  Currently, we do not insert page breaks when printing, as most forms use page breaks to break up the data entry process, and would not be helpful when printing.  Definitely something we can look into making an option.

We are working on [PDF & Word Merging](https://trello.com/c/6lmmtMMy) to support custom print templates, which will provide complete control over the format of printed documents produced by [Cognito Forms](https://ww.cognitoforms.com).

If the header bar with the form name, date, and status is printing on a separate page for you, please submit a bug report so we can take a look.  It should just be a single line at the top to provide context to the entry when printed.